# sample mean and sample variance of multiple variables

Tags: r, mean, variance

I have a csv file, mtcars that contains models of cars with differnt variables
[image]

I know that to find the mean, I just do mean(mtcars$mpg) and to find variance, var(mtcars$mpg). Instead of writing this a number of times, how would I display all the means and variance of each variable in one line? The first column in the dataset are strings, so how would I disregard that one column when calculating the mean and variance? Thanks.

Comment: `sapply(mtcars, mean)`, `sapply(mtcars, var)`. To skip the first column, `sapply(mtcars[, -1], mean)`. In the future, please don't post pictures of data. Copy/pasteable data is *great*, in valid R syntax. As are built-in data sets like `mtcars`, which everyone has already by default.

Comment: First one is correct. In `mtcars` the name of the car is the row name, not a column.

Comment: You can use `colMeans(mtcars[-1])` or `matrixStats::colVars(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]))`

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse`, we can reshape to 'long' format, then grouped by 'name' get the `mean` and `var`iance as `summarise`d output in two columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
mtcars %>% 
   rownames_to_column('model') %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -model) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(Mean = mean(value), Var = var(value))
```

---

Or another option is `summarise_if`

```
mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column('model') %>% 
    summarise_if(is.numeric, list(Mean = mean, Var = var)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything())
```

---

Or with `colMeans` and `matrixStats::colVars`

```
colMeans(mtcars[-1])
matrixStats::colVars(as.matrix(mtcars[-1]))
```

Comment: Try also using Rfast::colVars. My experiments say it is 2 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning User.

Try also using

```
Rfast::colVars(x)
```

My experiments say it is at least 2 times faster. A second alternative would be

```
Rfast2::colmeansvars(x)
```